# What's the best practice for building a Node.js REST API app with multiple database support?

Tags: node.js, database, express

Recently, I've built a Node.js REST API for a simple blog using Express.js to handle HTTP requests, and MySQL for persistence (I'm currently not using ORM: In my database access layer I call stored procedures directly).

[My architecture diagram looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPM0S.jpg)

But what if I want to ditch MySQL and start using MongoDB?

I think the best approach would be adding support in my app for both database systems, so that if I want to switch from MySQL to MongoDB or viceversa I'll have both database access layers ready (setting aside the data migration part).

**What's the best way to achieve this?** Ideally the best solution would involve just changing an app configuration property to point which database I want to use

---

Comment: Since they are different db systems (relational and no-relational) its a very difficult approach. Even serious ORM doesnt have this feature, but they are able to switch easily between relational databases

Answer (score 0):

That's heavily based on opinion and context.

Every time you need NodeJS to communicate with a database you have to use modules that accomodate for them to make the connection, querying and other actions easy. Even you were to write a module to abstract the databases by yourself you could only handle a few specific cases. There is no single module to handle all of them.

In large applications where multiple apis may be used simultaneously they are usually in different endpoints. Basically `/api/mongo` and `/api/mysql` and you write both of them like you are writing a single api and to make the change you just change your front-end requests.

For your specific case I would recommend you take a look at [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/). It has a cli that does what I said above programmatically and supports many different databases.